# Using different data frame for the same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found and example for the `%+%` operator in `ggplot2` to use a different data frame for the same plot. Examples are available [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/gg-add.html).

When I try this, I get an error message:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000), y=rnorm(1000))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
p
p %+% df[1:100,]
```

> Error in p %+% df[1:100, ] : x must be either a vector or a matrix

Did I misunderstood the example on the website?

**sessionInfo()**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] cfpscripts_0.4.0  seqinr_3.1-3      ade4_1.7-2        gridExtra_0.9.1   psych_1.5.4       reshape2_1.4.1    plyr_1.8.3        knitr_1.10.5      rMQanalysis_0.2.0 ggplot2_1.0.1     testthat_0.10.0  
[12] devtools_1.8.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0           git2r_0.10.1          tools_3.2.0           digest_0.6.8          memoise_0.2.1         gtable_0.1.2          lattice_0.20-31       curl_0.8              parallel_3.2.0       
[10] proto_0.3-10          stringr_1.0.0         imbproteomicsr_0.1.7  xml2_0.1.1            rversions_1.0.1       data.table_1.9.4      sp_1.1-1              magrittr_1.5          scales_0.2.5         
[19] cfppdfs_0.3.4         MASS_7.3-40           mnormt_1.5-3          splitstackshape_1.4.2 logspline_2.1.8       colorspace_1.2-6      labeling_0.3          stringi_0.5-5         munsell_0.4.2        
[28] chron_2.3-45          crayon_1.3.0          zoo_1.7-12
```

Comment: Works for me on `ggplot2_1.0.1`. Try updating your `ggplot2` package. Also you can see if `?"%+%"` finds a ggplot2 function

Comment: Just figured out that the `psych` package overwrites the `%+%` function. Is there a way to call the `ggplot2` version explizit? `ggplot2::%+%` did not work.

Comment: load `psych` before you load `ggplot2`?  or put single-back-quotes around `%+%` in `ggplot2:``%+%```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my question.

Comment: @BenBolker I wanted to try the `ggplot2:` notation since it seems to be more stable in case of errors but I can not get it to work. R always complains about `unexpected symbol in "p ggplot2"`. p is my graph and I try ggplot2::'%+%' but the ' are single back ticks which would now highlight my command. I tried also with only one colon, double back ticks and a lot of different combinations but always the same error.

Comment: you're right.  R's parser allows a limited set of characters to delimit an operator.  You *could* do "`%+%` <- ggplot2::`%+%`" (not sure if the back-ticks will come out right) to create a copy of the operator in your global workspace, but probably best just to be careful about loading `psych` and `ggplot2`.  You could add a test `if(find("%+%")[1]=="package:psych") stop("oops")` to your code ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is loading the `psych` package *after* `ggplot2`, which gives you a message:

> Attaching package: ‘psych’
>   The following objects are masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
>   %+%, alpha

Since R's parser allows a limited set of characters to delimit an operator, the ::+back-tick trick `` p ggplot2::`%+%` newdata `` won't work. Other than making sure to load `psych` before `ggplot2`, you could do

```
`%+%` <- ggplot2::`%+%`
```

to create *yet another* copy of the operator in your global workspace, but it's probably best just to be careful about loading `psych` and `ggplot2`.

You could add a test

```
if(find("%+%")[1]=="package:psych") stop("oops")
```

to your code to make sure this doesn't happen by accident ...

Comment: Actually id did the trick with reassigning the `%+%` to `%myadd%` within my function, just to make sure... I work a lot with the `psych` package and it is often loaded in the background and I didn't wanted to bother... I didn't understood why the back tick trick didn't work in my way, but now it is not completely clear ;-) but I got your solution, thanks.